# Widgetkit Slideshow

Tags: components, joomla2.5

I have installed the Widgetkit module to joomla 2.5 and it is working, however when I try to make a slideshow the html editor does not appear to actually add content to the slideshow, I have a html editor enabled on global configuration (TinyMCE) also tried another editor but still no joy. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Try contacting Yootheme as they are the developers of this extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [JCE](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/).
If it's still not working then go to JCE preferences and change there editor appearing in different places of admin panel.